# What can be the background when [Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"] is found in multiple files, not just one?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm currently following a Vue tutorial where you make a simple e-mail app, but the result of my test run doesn't display the content of the inbox as it should  (see the attached images. The first one is mine, and the other one is the correct version, which is how it should look like)

[image: withError]

[image: correctOne]

When I studied my own version with inspect to find out what could have gone wrong, the console stated that I got a Vue warning

```
Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"
```

, and it was found in multiple files, like

```
found in

---> <AppMessages> at C:\Users...(omitted for readability)...\sample-project\src\Messages.vue
       <AppInbox> at C:\Users...(omitted for readability)...\sample-project\src\Inbox.vue
         <AppContent> at C:\User...(omitted for readability)...\sample-project\src\Content.vue
           <App> at C:\Users...(omitted for readability)...\sample-project\src\App.vue
             <Root>
```

The content of the Messages.vue file is

```
<template>
    <table v-if="messages.length > 0"  class="table table-inbox table-hover">
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="message in messages" :class="{ unread: typeof message.isRead !== 'undefined' && !message.isRead }">
                <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" v-if="typeof message.isImportant !== 'undefined'">
                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>{{ message.from.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ message.subject }}</td>
                <td><i v-if="message.atachments.length > 0" class="fa fa-paperclip"></i></td>
                <td class="text-right">{{ message.date.fromNow() }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <p v-else>No messages here yet.</p>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props:{
            messages:{
                type: Array,
                required: true
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

, and I understand that neither one of v-if and v-else statements in the code above is executed because the property of 'length' is undefined and cannot be read and evaluated in the first place.

When I didn't test run some of the tutorial videos' code it was often simply because I had some typo, but usually it was just in one file where I typed wrong. On the other hand, this time I get the exact same error for multiple files at the same time. Can the cause of this 'undefined' stuff simply be some typo as well, or could there be some other reason?

Comment: Would you post the content of `Inbox.vue`?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but actually the problem has been solved by fixing the mistake found in the code shown above!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice a spelling error in `<i v-if="message.atachments.length > 0"` should it read `<i v-if="message.attachments.length > 0"` ?

Comment: That fixed the problem and now it's properly displayed, thank you! So the reason why the error was also found in other files like  Inbox.vue, Content.vue, App.vue was probably that they were trying to refer to some data deriving from Messages.vue?